# Check numbers in a range that contain or are divisible by 7

Tags: javascript

I don't know what is the problem with this code I just need to know
how many number from `Start` to `end` that divide by `7` or has `7`.

```js
const divideOrHasSeven = (start, end) => {
  var x = 0;
  for (i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    if (i % 7 || i.toString().indexOf("7")) { // if it is divide by 7 or has 7
      x += 1;
    }
  }
  return x;
};
```

Comment: Please do not post code in an image. Instead copy/paste the code as a [mcve] into the question

Comment: [Duplicate](//www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+indexOf+in+if+statement) of [indexOf methods in if statement](/q/59078636/4642212). Please read the documentation: [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), [Falsy](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `i.toString().indexOf('7')` will always return a truthy value EXCEPT (ironically) when 7 is actually in the number (inthe first position - index zero)

Change your conditional to `if (i%7===0 || i.toString().indexOf('7')>-1)`

Answer (score 1):

You had some problems with your code.
If you compare with this, I think you will understand where.

This `i.toString().indexOf('7')` will return `-1` if 7 is not found in string, which will be evaluated as `true`.
You also had some syntax errors.

```js
const divideOrHasSeven = (start, end) => {
    var x = 0;
    for (i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        if (i%7 === 0 || i.toString().indexOf('7') >= 0) {
            x += 1;
        }
    }
    return x
}

console.log(divideOrHasSeven(1, 200));
```